# Mapping .Net Core Runtime versions with .Net Core SDK versions

Tags: .net-core, version

I just went and got the latest .Net Core 3.1 runtime and SKD containers.

The latest version of the runtime is 3.1.10 and the latest version of the SDK is 3.1.404.

But according to this [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/), that is not a valid versioning structure.  It says that the minor versions of the SDK will follow a pattern similar to this formula:

```
 (Runtime Minor Version * 100) + SDK Actual Minor Version
```

So, a Runtime version of 3.1.5 would make SDK versions of 3.1.5xx where xx is the SDK minor version would be.

So by that logic, if the Runtime version is 3.1.10, then the SDK version should be 3.1.1004.

What am I missing?  Is that document just for .Net Core 2? or did Microsoft just give up on that and the documentation is old?  (The page was last edited this year).

**Is there a correlation between the Runtime and SDK versions of .Net Core?**

When I run `dotnet --info` on the SDK container it tells me that the Host is using 3.1.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't really a strict formula between the SDK and Runtime version numbers.

The formula is how the version numbers start. But when there is a new SDK update, they bump the multiplier but continue counting the version from there. They initial SDK versions for 3.1 were:

- 3.1.100
- 3.1.101
- 3.1.102

But they also released a new SDK feature band at the same time. That got the version 3.1.200. And the versioning continued from there:

- 3.1.100
- 3.1.101
- 3.1.102 + 3.1.200
- 3.1.103 + 3.1.201

Another SDK feature release happend after this:

- 3.1.104 + 3.1.202 + 3.1.300

And so on.

You can see a list of all 3.1 Runtime + SDK release versions here:

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1

Or you can work with them programmatically using https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/3.1/releases.json

Comment: So the MS Doc page I linked to is just wrong?  (It seems to be.. I posted a bug report that it was incorrect.)